# Loading CrossValidator Object Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I get an error saying that there is no training summary for cvModel.bestModel.  I can access the summary of cvModel_lasso but once I save and load it I can't view summary.  How do I view this summary?

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator, CrossValidatorModel

cv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, evaluator=regEval, numFolds=10)

cvModel_lasso = cv.fit(preppedDataDF)

cvModel_lasso.write().overwrite().save('myModelPath_lasso')
cvModel=CrossValidatorModel.load('myModelPath_lasso')

trainingSummary = cvModel.bestModel.summary
```

The error received:

```
RuntimeError: No training summary available for this LinearRegressionModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would save the best model, rather than the validator model as you have done i.e.

```
best_model = cvModel_lasso.bestModel
best_model.write().overwrite().save('myModelPath_lasso')
```

On loading back the `best_model`, you should be able to retrieve the summary.